# Can protoc or any tool do JSON-protobuf conversion?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

Protobuf is in binary format, and it has also equivalent text format and JSON format.

`protoc` has `--encode` and `--decode` option to do text-binary conversion.

But is there a small tool to do JSON-binary conversion? like below:

```bash
tool --encode input.json def.proto > pb-output.bin
```

and

```bash
tool --decode pb-input.bin def.proto > output.json
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [proto-convert](https://github.com/iamAzeem/proto-convert).

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. Did you create the tool for this question, ;), since I see it's less than a day?

Comment: Well, kind of and you're welcome! :-) Not completely true, though. ;-) I wrote this plugin earlier: [fluent-plugin-protobuf-http](https://github.com/iamAzeem/fluent-plugin-protobuf-http). So, I already had an idea and other POCs on how to go about it. See: [protobuf-log-sample](https://github.com/iamAzeem/protobuf-log-sample) and [protobuf-repeated-type-vs-any](https://github.com/iamAzeem/protobuf-repeated-type-vs-any). So, your question expedited its materialization. Cheers! :-)